# Binding a Property to a mvxBindableListView in Android

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I have a problem trying to bind a property of an object in a mvxBindableListView with MVVMCross and Android.

The structure of the classes is the next:

```
public class A 
{
    public string MyPropertyA1 { get; set; }
    public int MyPropertyA2 { get; set; }
}
public class B 
{
    public int MyPropertyB1 { get; set; }
    public int MyPropertyB2 { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int MyPropertyC1 { get; set; }
    public A MyPropertyA { get; set; }
    public B MyPropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

The mvxBindableListView is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mvx.mvxBindableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Android.Client"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Results'}}"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/detail_viewmodel" />
```

Where Results is: public ObservableCollection Results { get; set; }
and the detail_viewmodel is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Android.Client"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'MyPropertyA.MyPropertyA1'}}" />
```

When the application runs, it shows me the mvxBindableListView with the number of elements that contains the variable 'Results' , but the rows are empty.

Anyone know what is happening? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing the Tutorial application to use an email with:

```
    public class Thing
    {
        public string Life { get; set; }

        public Thing()
        {
            Life = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleEmail
    {
        public Thing MyThing { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }    
        public string Header { get; set; }    
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public SimpleEmail()
        {
            MyThing = new Thing();
        }
    }
```

And the template to include:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/email_header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/email_from"
local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'MyThing.Life'}}"
/>
```

This showed the Guid's fine.

Looking at your code, because your models do not support INotifyPropertyChanged, then I wonder if you are setting the ViewModel properties before you are binding?

To fix this, I might try:

```
public class A 
{
    public string MyPropertyA1 { get; set; }
    public int MyPropertyA2 { get; set; }
}
public class B 
{
    public int MyPropertyB1 { get; set; }
    public int MyPropertyB2 { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int MyPropertyC1 { get; set; }
    public A MyPropertyA { get; set; }
    public B MyPropertyB { get; set; }
    public C()
    {
       MyPropertyA = new A() { MyPropertyA1 = "TestValue" };
    }
}
```

If your app then shows "TestValue" then you know that the binding is working.

If you then need to get the right values shown, you have two choices:

1. Set the properties before you bind the view to the data
2. Somehow, somewhere on the binding chain signal the INotifyPropertyChange event so that the binding knows it has to refresh